# Showing users name on nav bar when logged in using ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to be able to replace Accounts tab on my navigation bar with the User's name when they logged in.  How would i go about doing that.  Would i have to use some sort of embedded ruby like <%=  @user.name %>

heres the html

```
   enter code here

<header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %> 
      <nav>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
          <li><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li> 
          <li><%= link_to "Help", help_path %></li> 
          <% if signed_in? %>
          <li><%= link_to "Users", '#' %></li> 
          <li id="fat-menu" class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
               Account
              <b class="caret"></b>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><%= link_to "Profile", user_path(current_user) %></li> 
              <li><%= link_to "Settings", '#' %></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li>
                <%= link_to "Sign out", signout_path, method: 'delete' %> 
              </li>
            </ul> 
          </li>
        <% else %>
          <li><%= link_to "Sign in", signin_path %></li>
        <% end %> 
       </ul>
      </nav>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= current_user.name %>
```